# ¿Cómo puedo especificar que quiero un dato en cierta columna en un txt desde php?

Tags: php, mysql, txt

Estoy haciendo un apartado que descargue los datos de mi base de datos en un archivo txt... Y necesito que empiece por su id y en la columna 30 del archivo txt aparezca el nombre del producto.

Algo así:

EL ID ES = rft23
Nombre = cheetos

y que en el txt quede

```
rft23                         cheetos
```

```
<?php
      $p = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM producto");
      $h = mysqli_fetch_array($p);
      $ar=fopen("archivo.txt","a") or die ("Error al crear");
      fwrite($ar, $h['id']);
      fwrite($ar, "\n");
      fseek($ar,30);
      fwrite($ar, $h['nombre']);
      fclose($ar);
    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: los txt tienen columnas???

Comment: Hasta abajo de un block de notas te dice en que fila y en que columna estas escribiendo.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intertar esto

```
require 'conexion.php'; 

$ar=fopen("archivo.txt","w") or die ("Error al crear");

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM producto)";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);

while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
fwrite($ar,'El ID es: '.$row['id']);

}
```

Puedes insertar un salto de linea con:

```
fwrite($ar, '' . PHP_EOL);
```

Al final de cada iteracion para que tu txt sea este ordenado